# Dynamic JSX Component Name issue caused by import/export pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm building a configurable Avatar component that composes different avatar characteristics components depending on the type of avatar we want to put together. E.g. A pirate avatar is composed from a PegLeg component and a Parrot component.

The end goal is to have a const mapping with all characteristics such that:

```
const characteristicMapping = {
  pegleg: PeglegComponent, // component needed in Pirate avatar
  parrot: ParrotComponent, // component needed in Pirate avatar
  wand: WandComponent, // not used in Pirate, but used in Wizard.
};
```

And then based on a prop (array of characteristics) we compose the characteristics we needed, e.g.

```
// For Pirate avatar with Pirate char. set to default value
const Avatar = ({ avatarCharacteristics = ['pegleg', 'parrot'] }) => (
  <div>
    {avatarCharacteristics.map(c => characteristicsMapping[c]).map(
      (AvatarComponent, i) => <AvatarComponent key={i} />)}
  </div>
);
```

My understanding is, as long as AvatarComponent has its first letter capitalized, this should work, and it does!

However, I seem to have issues depending on how `PeglegComponent` and `ParrotComponent` are imported.

I'm using a babel package named Easy Import to handling packages/namespaces.

Current both PeglegComponent/ParrotComponent (sep files) have Easy Import package names such as:

```
// @package Components/Avatar/Characteristics/PeglegComponent
export default PeglegComponent; 

// @package Components/Avatar/Characteristics/ParrotComponent
export default ParrotComponent;
```

One folder down from Characteristics, I have an index.js file that's laid out:

```
// @package Components/Avatar

import PeglegComponent from 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics/PeglegComponent';
import ParrotComponent from 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics/ParrotComponent';

export default {};
export { PeglegComponent, ParrotComponent };
```

So the imports in the composing Avatar component the imports look like:

```
import { PeglegComponent, ParrotComponent } from 'Components/Avatar';

const characteristicsMapping = {
  pegleg: PeglegComponent, // component needed for Pirate Avatar
  parrot: ParrotComponent, // component needed for Pirate Avatar
};

// For Pirate avatar with Pirate char. set to default value
const Avatar = ({ avatarCharacteristics = ['pegleg', 'parrot'] }) => (
  <div>
    {avatarCharacteristics.map(c => characteristicsMapping[c]).map(
      (AvatarComponent, i) => <AvatarComponent key={i} />)}
  </div>
);
```

In this scenario I get the error:

`Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports`

More importantly if I console.log `characteristicsMapping` I get `{pegleg: undefined, parrot: undefined}`

So for whatever reason the import is failing. The weird thing is, this seems to be solely a dynamic component name issue. E.g. If I do this it works, with the exact same import:

```
import { PeglegComponent, ParrotComponent } from 'Components/Avatar';

// For Pirate avatar with Pirate char. set to default value
const Avatar = () => (
  <div>
    <PeglegComponent />
    <ParrotComponent />
  </div>
);
```

At first I thought that I simply couldn't dynamic component name, that feature went away, however, then I discovered this would work.

```
import PeglegComponent from 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics/PeglegComponent';
import ParrotComponent from 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics/ParrotComponent';

const characteristicsMapping = {
  pegleg: PeglegComponent, // component needed for Pirate Avatar
  parrot: ParrotComponent, // component needed for Pirate Avatar
};

// For Pirate avatar with Pirate char. set to default value
const Avatar = ({ avatarCharacteristics = ['pegleg', 'parrot'] }) => (
  <div>
    {avatarCharacteristics.map(c => characteristicsMapping[c]).map(
      (AvatarComponent, i) => <AvatarComponent key={i} />)}
  </div>
);
```

Also if I have an index.js file in the same folder as PeglegComponent/ParrotComponent and then import from there it works.

In `Components/Avatar/Characteristics` there's a index.js with:

```
// @package Components/Avatar/Characteristics

import PeglegComponent from 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics/PeglegComponent';
import ParrotComponent from 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics/ParrotComponent';

export default {};
export { PeglegComponent, ParrotComponent };
```

Then this works:

```
import { PeglegComponent, ParrotComponent } from 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics';

const characteristicsMapping = {
  pegleg: PeglegComponent, // component needed for Pirate avatar
  parrot: ParrotComponent, // component needed for Parrot avatar
};

// For Pirate avatar with Pirate char. set to default value
const Avatar = ({ avatarCharacteristics = ['pegleg', 'parrot'] }) => (
  <div>
    {avatarCharacteristics.map(c => characteristicsMapping[c]).map(
      (AvatarComponent, i) => <AvatarComponent key={i} />)}
  </div>
);
```

If I import stuff from Characteristics's index.js into Avatar's index.js (one directory up), fails again.

So I have a few work arounds, to get over my issue, but it does seem inconsistent that importing from `Components/Avatar` I can directly do , but if I try to construct an array of Components from an object mapping, that the component comes up undefined.

Wanted to see if anyone could explain to me why.. is this a JSX issue, React issue or an Easy Import issue? Or one with my understanding of how named/default exports work...?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a simple syntax error.You should add quotes on every import like this:

```
import PeglegComponent from './Components/Avatar/Characteristics/PeglegComponent';
```

Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Ah, I'm using Easy Import which allows you to define // @package Components/Avatar/Characteristics/PeglegComponent

And then do an import on 'Components/Avatar/Characteristics/PeglegComponent' without the ./

Comment: I believe you still need the quotes. “ “

Comment: If you edit the original post this won't be a valid question anymore. Just accept this answer if it solves the problem and leave the question as it is.

Comment: It doesn't fix the issue. Current thinking is its a bug with Easy Import. Wasn't aware of editing etiquette, but in my mind, surrounding import paths with single quotes does not invalidate the question, only fixes a typo. My original code does have the quotes, they were lost in the writing of the question, mea culpa.